# Standard Error for Relative Risk

Tags: r

I am trying to code the standard error for relative risk. In many cases I am obtaining infinity for SE and NaN for confidence limits. I was wondering if I need to specify limits for parameters in order to have a finite standard error. Heres my code

```
    set.seed(111) 
    k<-63
    n<-60
    xt<-NULL
    xc<-NULL

    pt<-rbeta(k,3,3)   # treatment effect
    pc<-rbeta(k,1,3)   # control effect
    true_RR<-pt/pc   # True Relative Risk

    for(i in 1:k)
    {
    xt<-cbind(xt,rbinom(300,n,pt[i]))

    xc<-cbind(xc,rbinom(300,n,pc[i]))
     }
    a<-xt
    b<-n-a
    c<-xc
    d<-n-c

    RR<-xt/xc

    for (i in 1:300){

    for (j in 1:63) 
    {
    if (xc[i,j]==0)
    {
     RR[i,j]<-0
     }}}
     se_rate<-sqrt((b/(a*(a+b)))+(d/(c*(c+d))))

     l_cl<-RR*exp(-1.96*se_rate)
     u_cl<-RR*exp(1.96*se_rate)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting `Inf` is because you are dividing by 0. In particular, you set

```
xc = cbind(xc,rbinom(300,n,pc[i]))
c = xc
```

and later on calculate:

```
d/(c*(c+d))
```

So there is a non-zero probability of setting `c` equal to zero. What you should do instead is a statistics problem and we don't have enough information to give you sensible advice.

Comment: I do understand the reason for getting Inf for standard error. But my question was more because I am trying to generate data and asses it using the standard method as well as BUGS. IF I get SE=Inf I am unable to calculate 95% standard confidence interval and hence coverage. So my point was whether we should apply limit to the choice of parameters a,b,c,d as in a,c>0 or just report what we are getting?